# Angular 2 - return field from one firestore document from a service

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a Nativescript Angular 2 application with firebase as my backend. I only want to get the firstname from an user by his uid. When I console.log() the function outside of my service, it returns an empty string (""). I assume that it has something to do with the .then() promise. How can I fix this?

user.service.ts

```
getFirstNameByUid(uid: string): string {
    const userDocument = firebaseWebApi.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);

    userDocument.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            return doc.data().firstname;
        } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    });

    return "";
}
```

app.component.ts

```
console.log(this.userService.GetFirstNameByUid("31faklj3193"); // Returns ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the empty string before your Firebase request has an opportunity to return the result from the document.

If you need it to wait, use a promise with async/await to return the value.

Should be something like:

```
async getFirstNameByUid(uid: string): string {
    const userDocument = firebaseWebApi.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);

    const doc = await userDocument.get();

    if (doc.exists) {
        return doc.data().firstname;
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: in app.component.ts, console.log( the function ) returns "[object promise]" now

Comment: Put a debugger in the if (doc.exists()) and check the type. I'm not sure about which firebase api you're using. If you link which lib it is in the question, I can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the output type.

```
getFirstNameByUid(uid: string) {
    const userDocument = firebaseWebApi.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid);
    return userDocument.get().then((doc) => {
         const result = doc.exists ? doc.data().firstname : null;
         console.log(result);
         return result;
    });
}
```